# How to Return Dynamic Table using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables `tblCustBilIinfo` with

```
(Bill_no,Customer_Name,date,bill_Amount,deposit,Balance)
And tblincome with (Tid,date,name,amount)
```

Now I need to show record like this

```
Select  c.Bill_Amount,I.Amount ,C.balance from tblcustBillInfo as C, tblincome As I 
where C.customer_Name ='rakesh' 
and date between '24-06-2016' And '30-06-2016'
```

Now selected record is like in Balance sheet format Like in accounting (debit credit.)
First Select Bill_ amount then debit amount of customer.

And also need to select date column but it values is selected from above tables on the bases of selected record.

Please can any one Help me to solve.
Or guide me to use procedure or function to achieve that task.

Answer (score 1):

NO, you can't get data from both table like that unless doing a `JOIN` between the tables either with a related column (OR) using a common naming column.Some thing like

```
select  c.Bill_Amount,
I.Amount ,
C.balance 
from tblcustBillInfo as C JOIN tblincome As I ON C.id = I.Tid
where C.customer_Name = 'rakesh' 
and C.date between '24-06-2016' And '30-06-2016'
```

Comment: Or any other way to do that... using procedure or function

Comment: Well technically he is doing a cross join so if he limited/established the relationship in the where clause he could do it....but I think there is more to the issue than that it appears that he really is thinking more of a union all between to tables (one table = credits one = debits).  The question still stands of which column(s) will signify the same unique information between the tables as the only one that makes since in the table definitions he provided is name/customer name but I am hoping that is not the case if that is a free form field.